# Why is $f:\mathbb{R^+}\to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x)=x^2$ not an invertible function?

Tags: functions

Why is $f:\mathbb{R^+}\to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x)=x^2$ not an invertible function? I know the answer: *because it's not onto*, but what is problem with it? what does it break the invertibility?
P.s.: $\mathbb{R^+}=\{x\in \mathbb{R}|x‎\geq‎ 0\}$

Comment: What is the definition of an invertible function? The idea of why it does not work is that for a function $f:A\to B$ to be invertible you want that *every* element of $B$ is mapped to an element of $A$ uniquely by the inverse of $f$.

Comment: Does $\mathbb R$ contain only nonnegative reals?

Comment: @LandonCarter: Yes. I edited my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the given domain, $f$ is in fact one-to-one. But it is not onto the given codomain, because there is no $x$ with $f(x)=-1$. If the codomain is changed to $\mathbb{R}^+$, then $f$ is indeed invertible.

Comment: I told myself that I know $f$ isn't onto and I do know that $f:\mathbb{R^+}\to \mathbb{R^+}$ is bijective and so invertible. My problem is that: What problem is created if the function is not onto? Suppose you want to write the answer on a final exam sheet.

Comment: @Sisabe The domain of the inverse would be the given codomain, i.e. $\mathbb{R}$, but there is no way to define the inverse at $-1$.

Comment: because $\sqrt{-1}$ is undefined. right?

Comment: @Sisabe That's one way to say it, yes.

Answer (score 1):

There is a good explanation from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function):

When using codomains, the inverse of a function $ƒ: X → Y$ is required to have domain $Y$ and codomain $X$. For the inverse to be defined on all of $Y$, every element of $Y$ must lie in the range of the function $f$. A function with this property is called onto or a surjection. Thus, a function with a codomain is invertible if and only if it is both injective (one-to-one) and surjective (onto). Such a function is called a one-to-one correspondence or a bijection, and has the property that every element $y\in Y$ corresponds to exactly one element $x \in X$.

Answer (score 1):

It's not surjective, for $f^{-1}$ it needs to have the entire domain $\mathbb{R}$, so what is $f^{-1}(-2)$?